# Problemas com Ajax em projeto PHP MVC

Tags: php, ajax, mvc, twig

Estou com dificuldades para usar o ajax com html.

Tenho um arquivo html que responde perguntas de um chat e coloquei o ajax abaixo ajax. Ele redireciona para a controller perguntas e o método responder. O status da requisição é 200, mas nada acontece. Debuguei e vi que o ajax nem acessa o método, não passa nenhuma das variáveis que eu preciso.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".form-response").on('click',function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var seller_id = $(this).attr("seller_id");
    var dataValue = $(this).attr("data-value");
    var resposta = $("#resposta-pergunta-" + dataValue).val();
    console.log(dataValue);
    console.log(resposta);
    console.log(seller_id);

    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url : '../perguntas/responder',
      data: {
        id: dataValue,
        resposta: resposta,
        seller_id: seller_id

      }}).done(function(data){

        console.log($("#card-" + dataValue).hide());
        alert("Respondido com Sucesso! - Ajax");

      }).fail(function(){

        alert('Problema para RESPONDER');

      });
    return false;   });
```

Quando clico no botão responder, aparecem as informações no meu console.

O meu projeto está em MVC e estou usando o twig para renderizar os templates.
Eu tenho uma arquivo layout.html, que tem o cabeçalho e outro arquivo chamado formulario.html, que estaria entre o {% block formulario %} e {% endblock %}. Meu ajax está junto com o formulario.html

Answer (score 0):

Já verificou se o evento de click está sendo acionado? Tente imprimir algum texto estático abaixo do evento de click para verificar se está acionando o evento.

```
$(".form-response").on('click',function(e){
 console.log('Está acionando o evento');
 ...
```

Comment: Sim, as mensagens aparecem.

Comment: O problema pode está na url. Tente utilizar a url absoluta. Exemplo: htttp://www.seusite.com.br/perguntas/responder

Answer (score 0):

Neste ponto:

```
url : '../perguntas/responder',
```

deveria ser o **"arquivo.ext"** ex: `'../perguntas/responder.php'`, que contém o método que trata sua requisição (os dados do `data: {...}`) por exemplo e retorna o resultado em `success: function(data)`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

Verifique o **Id ou Name** com cuido no seu HTML e confirme se estão iguais no arquivo  e tente usar essa sintaxe, no seu controller receba **json**:

```
   jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../perguntas/responder",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
             id: dataValue,
        resposta: resposta,
        seller_id: seller_id
},
        success: function(data)
        {    
            alert("sucesso");
        },
        error: function (request, status, erro) {

                alert("erro");                                      

             },
                 complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                //colocar aqui algo que deseja que faça ao terminar todo o processo (finnaly)
              }
       });
```